# react-native-navigation: showOverlay problem on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)'s showOverlay to present an overlay over another screen. The other screen, is shown using [react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer), which is used to present a pdf file. My goal is to show a button above the file viewer.
On iOS this works well but on Android, the view is added to the screen but is shown **under** the presented file viewer.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

```
const overlayLayout: Layout = {
    component: {
        id: `OVERLAY_BUTTON`,
        name: `OVERLAY_BUTTON`,
        options: {
            layout: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                componentBackgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            overlay: {
                interceptTouchOutside: false
            }
        },
        passProps: overlayButtonProps
      }
}

Navigation.showOverlay(overlayLayout)

FileViewer
    .open(localDocument.localUrl)
    .catch(error => {
      ErrorReportService.logNonFatalError(`failed to open document of extension: ${fileExtension}\nerror: ${error}`)
    })
```